# Do we add "to" the second verb (paint) because it's in the infinitive?

Tags: verbs

> 1. Can you help **me paint** the hall this weekend?
> 2. Can you help **me to paint** the hall this weekend?

Do we add "to" the second verb (paint) because it's in the infinitive?

Comment: "Help" is one of a few verbs that can take a bare infinitival complement, but it is optional: Can you help me (to) paint the hall this weekend?

Answer (score 1):

*Help* can be followed by an object and infinitive, with or without "to".
So, both are correct.
The first statement (without "to") is common in an informal style.
Ref:'Practical English Usage' by Michael Swan ELBS

Comment: Answers should be supported by reasonable evidence. Though reasonable checking that the question isn't a duplicate should take place first.

Comment: Added reference

Comment: Reasonable evidence consists of an attributed quote from a recognised reference work. But you might like to read John Lawler's answer at the duplicate; you'll see that it was heavily upvoted. (Mind you, so were others that I actually downvoted as being too prescriptive.)